# Drupal autodiscover error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

We were getting lots of error in Drupal logs related to "`autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`". To avoid it we have already tried the possible way to serve or block the request. Reference Link: https://docs.acquia.com/articles/avoiding-404-error-messages-your-logs

Finally two factor authentication is enabled for this file in web application firewall. I want to know:

How to check if this service is relevant for my website?

If it is not required what is recommend way to block these request?

Comment: From which module this error is coming? Please check that module, may be it is no configured correctly.

Comment: Please check below sample: 
page not found xx-xx-2016 14:15 autodiscover/autodiscover.xml Anonymous (not verified). This URL is request is coming from different country. Not sure if it is related to specific module.

Comment: It seems like some bot is trying to open that page from your site. it is not there, hence logging 404 error.

Comment: I am not able to find exactly how to handle this error. As mentioned we have blocked in firewall but not sure if this is correct. There are some details provided in this link: https://www.webmasterworld.com/analytics/3858104.htm

Comment: This isn't a Drupal issue. Autodiscover is most likely related to exchange. Requests reaching your web server generally indicate an misconfiguration elsewhere: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900169(v=exchg.150).aspx